# require() and $ not defined in electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I added a piece of code to add jquery code in html file of electron app. but every time when app started in debug console section it shows require() and $ is not defined. what is the solution of this problem ?

[image of problem section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE6fj.png)

## Hello world

```
<button>click</button>

<script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $("h1").css("color", "red");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: there is no javascript function called `require()` are you mixing php with JS?

Comment: I'm sorry Dan. but in require() is available in any package of node js to procure different modules

Comment: Hi, if my answer below is helpful feel free to upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

To use Node.js's `require` function you must enable `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` in the `BrowserWindow` options.

Example:

```
new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
    },
    // Other options here.
});
```

[All BrowserWindow options](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions). Search for `nodeIntegration`.

`nodeIntegration` used to be `true` by default. But in v5.0.0 they changed the default to `false`.

[Link to issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4362)